# react-native run-android error: SDK location is not found, but it exists in the path

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-emulator

Following the [react-native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#2-install-the-android-sdk), I have installed `Android 8.0 (Oreo)` and have completed the rest of the instructions. The only difference is that I have defined the platform variables in `.bashrc` and not `.bash_profile`.

When I want to run my react-native application, I get the error message: `Build failed with an exception.`

Here are the relevant log messages:

```
sudo react-native run-android
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

The project built for me does not contain the `local.properties` file; but, I already have the variable `ANDROID_HOME` in my path as shown below:

```
$ printenv | grep Android
ANDROID_HOME=/home/amir/Android/Sdk
PATH=/home/amir/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/amir/Android/Sdk/tools/bin:/home/amir/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/amir/Android/Sdk/emulator
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your React Native app directory.
2. Navigate to your-app/android/
3. Create a simple text file and call it local.properties
4. Add the following code to this file (Don’t forget to replace “your-username” with your actual username.):

   sdk.dir = /Users/your-username/Library/Android/sdk
5. That’s it! run “react-native run-android” command again or use Android Studio to run the project.

Comment: thanks, I did totally forget about this question, apparently, react-native specifically looks for `.bash_profile` and reads from it. so I created that and added an if condition in `.bashrc` to load it, and everything worked fine